# Python break loop with one line of code without using enumerate()

Tags: python, loops, break

If I want to add a break to my `for` or `while` loop at certain iteration can it be done without adding counter?

```
    i=1
    for line in zip(*input):
        print(format_row.format(*line))
        if i > 3: break
        i += 1
```

also without `enumerate()`:

```
    for i, line in enumerate(zip(*input)):
        print(format_row.format(*line))
        if i > 3: break
```

**EDIT:**

Please solution without including additional libraries.

I don't want to use enumerate because i have to edit code in for statement too much, its a temporary break for example to print N number of lines rather than 1000 lines, so debugging can be fast. I want to add quick `break` and then remove it without need to modify original code of `for` loop.

I want to add 2 lines maximum one outside the `for` loop another inside the `for` loop, how to make this work, function will be stored elsewhere and reused many times so its not a problem, function can be as long as required.

```
    # function does not count as extra code because it is reusable
    def check(num):
        if num > 3:
            return True
        else:
            num += i


    # line 1
    i = 1

    for line in zip(*input):
        print(format_row.format(*line))
        
        # line 2
        if check(i): break
```

Comment: `enumerate` is the way to go here.

Comment: write a function to replace zip. it zips but only generates x items. if you shadow zip you won't even have to change your code except for one import. provided all your loops use zip

Comment: @diggusbickus wonderful could make function `zip3()` to only trip first 3 parameters from the big list, but this would only work for `for` loops where i use `zip()`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `range()` zipped to your iterator, thus limiting your loop without the addition of lines or break statements.

```py
# range limits the loop
for line, _ in zip(zip(*input), range(3)):
    print(format_row.format(*line))
```

Comment: Idea was to not modify the beginning line of `for` loop in any way, so i could quickly remove the limit without much thinking if its going to break the code or not.